# how to update a tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]i wrote a programm, that gets weather data from a api, and now im working on a interface, but when i want a new temperature in the same label it doesnt work.

```
import requests
from tkinter import *

global stadt

TOKEN = "rrrrrrrrrr"
a = "jaaa"

root = Tk()

root.title("Wetter")
root.geometry("300x150")


def get_entry():
    stadt = Entry1.get()
    url = f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={stadt}&appid={TOKEN}"
    f = requests.get(url).json()

    temperatur = f["main"]["temp"]
    temperatur = temperatur - 273.15
    luftdruck = f["main"]["pressure"]

    alltext= f"Die Temperatur in {stadt} beträgt {round(temperatur)}°C\nDer Luftdruck in {stadt} beträgt {luftdruck}Ba"

    string = StringVar()
    lab = Label(root, text=alltext)
    lab.pack()
    string.set(alltext)
    

    

Label1 = Label(root, text="Bitte Stadt eingeben")
Label1.pack()

Entry1 = Entry(root)
Entry1.pack()



Button1 = Button(root, text="Senden", command=get_entry)
Button1.pack()


root.mainloop()

"""temperatur = u[2][2]
luftdruck = u[2][4]

temperatur = temperatur -273.15



print("Temperatur = ",round(temperatur),"°C")
print("Luftdruck = ",round(luftdruck),"Pa")
```

my goal is to update a label, without creating the same label again

on the picutre you can see the problem, i want it so that the text overwrites other one

Comment: Please don't re-ask questions. How is this any different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71162430/16775594)? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332271/16775594.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    lab = Label(root, text=alltext)
    lab.pack()
```

with

```
    Label1['text'] = alltext
```

and I wouldn't bother with the `StringVar`
But if you want to use `StringVar` that needs to be defined in the main code before `Label1` is made, eg `tvar = StringVar`. The inital `text` in `Label1` in this code would be assigned to ``` tvar``. And then inside ``` Label1`do`textvariable = tvar`. Then inside` get_entry`do`tvar.set(alltext)`. Also remove` lab``` label.

Best not use `string` as a variable name to avoid possible keyword conflict with Python.